# Rewrite header Location from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: nginx

Nginx adds a Location header in its reply. This one is in HTTP. I would like to replace it by HTTPS.

I tried with proxy_redirect.

With the hard URL, it works:

```
proxy_redirect http://www.mywebsite.com/fr/connexion?toUrl=%2Ffr https://www.mywebsite.com/fr/connexion?toUrl=%2Ffr;
```

However, I can't integrate RegEx in the command to make it work every time.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: You do not need to specify the entire URL, try: `proxy_redirect http:// https://;`

Comment: It's even simpler than I thought. I confirm that it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As Richard Smith said, it is not necessary to use a REGEX. Simply fill in the following directive:

```
proxy_redirect http:// https://;
```

or

```
proxy_redirect http://www.yourwebsite.com/ https://www.yourwebsite.com/;
```

Credit to [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) for the answer